# Why does querySelector not work with v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a simple `div` with a `v-for` loop that displays items on a page. These items have a `class` on them which I would like to select using Javascript's `querySelector` method.

```
<div class="product-feed">
  <div v-for="Product in ProductFeed" :key="Product.ProductID" class="product-item" >
    <Product-Vue-Component :Product="Product"></Product-Vue-Component>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
...
setup() {
  async function loadFeed(){
    await nextTick();
    let element1 = document.querySelector('.product-feed'); 
    console.log(`element1`, element1) // this works and displays the element

    let element2 = document.querySelector('.product-item:last-of-type'); 
    console.log(`element2`, element2) // this comes back as null
  }
}

  onMounted(()=> {
    loadFeed();
  })
}
...
</script>
```

Even though I am waiting for the DOM to render using `nextTick()`, the function `loadFeed()` cannot pick up on any item that is in the `v-for` loop.

I need to detect items in the `v-for` loop so that I can implement an infinite scroll feature where more items are loaded as the user scrolls to the bottom of the list of `.product-item` elements (hence `:last-of-type` pseudo selector)

Where is it going wrong and is it possible to select elements this way?

Comment: Everything works in isolated example: https://jsfiddle.net/matvey_andreyev/4qgny59j/2/ Are you sure that your ProductFeed is available at the onMounted + nextTick time?

Comment: @MatveyAndreyev Thank you for the test, it must be a race issue then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set ref on div with `class="product-item"`

```
<div ref="el" v-for="Product in ProductFeed" :key="Product.ProductID" class="product-item" >
```

then in setup function :

```
const el = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
    loadFeed()
  })

async function loadFeed(){
  await nextTick();
    let element1 = document.querySelector('.product-feed'); 
    console.log(`element1`, element1) // this works and displays the element

    console.log(el.value) 
  }
}
return {el}
```

Comment: How would you get the last `.product-item`?

Comment: Hey mate, i tested and el.value gets last element

Answer (score 0):

Please, use refs for that just add ref attribute to the container `ref="productFeed"` and get this element  with

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
...    
const productFeed = ref(null)
...
return {
    productFeed
}
```

Then you can use productFeed.value as a variable, containing dom element

Comment: And for loops use [this](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#usage-inside-v-for)

Comment: I need `product-item` not `ProductFeed`

Comment: For that i've left a link for you write `:ref="el => { if (el) divs[i] = el }"` on your `product-item` element create a variable for your elements `const divs = ref([])`, clear it on update `onBeforeUpdate(() => {
        divs.value = []
      })`,
and use `console.log(divs.value)` as an array of domElements

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [refs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/array-refs.html#frontmatter-title) like this:

```html
<div
  v-for="Product in ProductFeed" :ref="`product--${Product.id}`">
</div>
```